# How was Switzerland transliterated into Chinese?

Tags: pronunciation

So, my real question is: did 瑞 used to be pronounced *suì* in 官话?

My roundabout way at getting to this is from the transliteration of Switzerland.

---

Let's look at Chengduese.《现代汉语方言音库 • 成都话音档》records 瑞 with two pronunciations. One being:

> zuei²¹³

which could be roughly written in faux-"pinyin" as *rui*; which approximately (details aside) matches most MSM pronunciations.

and:

> suei²¹³

which is essentially (for our purposes here) *sui*.

---

Now, the rule of thumb for 老派 Chengduese is that names and places are read *sui* and not *rui*. Which would make the pronunciation of 瑞士 something more akin to *sui si* - which sounds much closer to the actual pronunciation of Switzerland. What makes for an even better case for this pronunciation is a comparison to Japanese. The Japanese pronunciation of Switzerland is Suisu (スイス) and it's Ateji (当て字) is **瑞西**.

---

How was Switzerland transliterated into Chinese? Was it through some topolect -or- did 瑞 originally carry the pronunciation *sui*?

edit: I supposed 瑞典 (Sweden) might also be an interesting case to look into - with similar *sui/swe* sounds.

edit #2: Looking at [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%91%9E) Min nan/Hakka/Cantonese all seem to be much closer to *sui* than *rui* also.

edit #3: Wiktionary’s entry for 瑞士 does confirm some things:

> From French Suisse, borrowed through a southern Chinese dialect (where 瑞 is pronounced with an s- initial). See also 瑞典 (Ruìdiǎn).

But it’s sorely lacking specifics.

edit #4: [apparently](http://blueiris4.lofter.com/post/2e6b70_59a85f1) 山东 topolect also reads 瑞 as sui.

edit #5: Grand Ricci also gives the pronunciation: shuì.

Comment: zdic has for 瑞:  [海陆腔] sui5 sui5 [客语拼音字汇] sui4 [陆丰腔] sui6 [东莞腔] sui3 [台湾四县腔] sui5 [客英字典] sui5 sui5 [宝安腔] sui5 [梅县腔] shui5 [沙头角腔] sui5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Did 瑞 used to be pronounced suì in 官話?

It was pronounced far closer to **suì** than today’s **ruì**, and more than enough to warrant the use of 瑞 as a transcription for *Switzerland* or *Sweden*.

> [image]
>
> Excerpt from
> 元・周德清[《中原音韻》](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhongyuan_Yinyun),
> detailing the phonology of 13th Century Central Plains speech, a.k.a.
> [Old Mandarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Mandarin). The
> characters 睡, 稅, 說, and 瑞 are pronounced identically. The expected
> Mandarin reflex of 瑞 is **shuì**.
>
> [image]
>
> Excerpt from the Ming Dynasty publication 《洪武正韻》, which details the speech of [Ming-era Mandarin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandarin_(late_imperial_lingua_franca)). The dictionary gives the *Fanqie* of 瑞 as 殊偽切.

Whatever changed the pronunciation to **r-** must have happened relatively recently...

Comment: Any idea where the Chinese translations for Switzerland and Sweden came from?

Comment: @user3306356 the name of Sweden supposedly was made up during the Qing Dynasty (see http://www.kina.cc/ac/history/sweden.htm). Of course, I don't know where the webmaster got the source from, so I can't confirm. However, [Draft History of Qing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draft_History_of_Qing) says the same thing \(see [清史稿](https://zh.wikisource.org/wiki/%E6%B8%85%E5%8F%B2%E7%A8%BF/%E5%8D%B7159)\)